# Hangouts Contact is missing

Tags: google-hangouts

I had a contact in my list for a month, now I don't see the person in my list. The last time I saw the person, their status was "last seen 4 weeks". Did that contact blocked me?

I doubt if the person used the hide feature then it removed the contact from my list. Did that happen?